# iOS development Swift Custom Cells

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I'm developing an app in Swift and I have problem with Custom Cells. I have one Custom Cell and when you click on Add button it creates another Custom Cell. Cell has 3 textfields, and 2 buttons. Those textfields are name, price, and amount of the ingredient of meal that I am creating. When I use only one Custom Cell or add one more to make it two, the data is stored properly. But when I add 2 Custom Cell (3 Custom Cells in total) I have problem of wrong price, only last two ingredients are calculated in price. When I add 3 Custom Cells (4 Custom Cells in total) it only recreates first cell with populated data like in first cell.
On finish button tap, I get an fatal error: Found nil while unwrapping Optional value.

View Controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddMealViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameTF: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var addMealsCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var finishButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addMealTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UILabel!
    let currency = "$" // this should be determined from settings
    var priceTotal = "0"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addMealTableView.delegate = self
        addMealTableView.dataSource = self
        borderToTextfield(textField: mealNameTF)
        mealNameTF.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            return true;
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return counter
    }

    var counter = 1

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return counter
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
            "addMealsCell", for: indexPath) as! AddMealsTableViewCell

        borderToTextfield(textField: (cell.amountTF)!)
        borderToTextfield(textField: (cell.ingredientNameTF)!)
        //borderToTextfield(textField: cell.normativeTF)
        borderToTextfield(textField: (cell.priceTF)!)



        return cell

    }


    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        counter += 1

        addMealTableView.register(AddMealsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "addMealsCell")
        addMealTableView.reloadData()

    }



    @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       mealNameTF.text = ""
        for c in 0..<counter{
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: c, section:0)
            let cell = addMealTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AddMealsTableViewCell
            cell.amountTF.text = ""
            cell.ingredientNameTF.text = ""
          //  cell.normativeTF.text = ""
            cell.priceTF.text = ""
        }
        productPrice.text = "\(currency)0.00"
        priceTotal = "0"
        counter = 1
    }

    @IBAction func finishButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for c in (0..<counter){
            if let cell = addMealTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: c, section: 0)) as? AddMealsTableViewCell {
                cell.amountTF.delegate = self
                cell.ingredientNameTF.delegate = self
                // cell.normativeTF.delegate = self
                cell.priceTF.delegate = self

                guard cell.priceTF.text?.isEmpty == false && cell.amountTF.text?.isEmpty == false && mealNameTF.text?.isEmpty == false && cell.ingredientNameTF.text?.isEmpty == false
                    else {
                        return
                }

                if cell.priceTF.text?.isEmpty == false{
                //    if (true) {
                    let tfp = Double((cell.priceTF.text!))!*Double((cell.amountTF.text!))!
                    var ttp = Double(priceTotal)
                    ttp! += tfp
                    priceTotal = String(ttp!)
              //  }
                    }}
            }


        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newMeal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Meal", into: context)
        let mealName = mealNameTF.text
        newMeal.setValue(mealName, forKey: "name")
        newMeal.setValue(priceTotal, forKey: "price")
        do {
            try context.save()

            print("Spremljeno")
        } catch  {
            print("Neki error")
        }

        productPrice.text = currency + priceTotal
    }

    @IBAction func addNewIngredientButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


    }
    func borderToTextfield(textField: UITextField){
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        textField.tintColor = UIColor.white
        textField.textColor = UIColor.white
        textField.textAlignment = .center

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true;
    }
}
```

Cell

```
class AddMealsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var DropMenuButton: DropMenuButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addNewIngredient: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ingredientNameTF: UITextField!

   // @IBOutlet weak var normativeTF: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var amountTF: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var priceTF: UITextField!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.endEditing(true)
        return true;
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.amountTF.text = ""
        self.priceTF.text = ""
        self.ingredientNameTF.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func DropMenuButton(_ sender: DropMenuButton) {
        DropMenuButton.initMenu(["kg", "litre", "1/pcs"], actions: [({ () -> (Void) in
            print("kg")
            sender.titleLabel?.text = "kg"
        }), ({ () -> (Void) in
            print("litre")

            sender.titleLabel?.text = "litre"
        }), ({ () -> (Void) in
            print("1/pcs")
            sender.titleLabel?.text = "1/pcs"
        })])
    }

    @IBAction func addNewIngredient(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let name = ingredientNameTF.text
        let amount = amountTF.text
        let price = priceTF.text
        //  let normative = normativeTF.text

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newIngredient = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Ingredient", into: context)

       newIngredient.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
       // newIngredient.setValue(normative, forKey: "normative")
       newIngredient.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")
       newIngredient.setValue(price, forKey: "price")

        do {

            try context.save()
            print("Spremljeno")
        } catch  {
            print("Neki error")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very difficult to read, but I suspect the problem may be here:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return counter
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return counter
}
```

You're returning the same number of rows for both the sections and rows for sections. So if you have 1 ingredient you are saying there is 1 section with 1 row. But if you have 2 ingredients you are saying there are 2 sections, each with 2 cells (4 cells total).

There are many other things to fix with your code, here are a few:

The biggest thing is that you are making this very difficult with the `counter` variable you have. If instead you have an array of ingredients

```
var ingredients = [Ingredient]()
```

You can use that to setup everything for the count of your table. Something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ingredients.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
        "addMealsCell", for: indexPath) as! AddMealsTableViewCell

    let ingredient = ingredients[indexPath.row]

    cell.ingredientNameTF.text = ingredient.name
    cell.normativeTF.text = ingredient.normative
    cell.amountTF.text = ingredient.amount
    cell.priceTF.text = ingredient.price

    return cell
}
```

All of these can be set in interface builder (you dont need lines of code in your view did load for them):

```
    addMealTableView.delegate = self
    addMealTableView.dataSource = self
    mealNameTF.delegate = self
```

This line should be in your `viewDidLoad` function, you only need to register the class once, you're doing it everytime add is pressed.

```
addMealTableView.register(AddMealsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "addMealsCell")
```

Your action names should be actions

```
 @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
 @IBAction func resetButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
 @IBAction func finishButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
```

> Thanks. Now when that ViewController loads I have no cells. My array is now empty so I have to implement some code to addButton which creates another cell and reloads tableView. How can I do that?

You just need to add a new ingredient object to the ingredients array and reload the data of the table view.

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let newIngredient = Ingredient()
    ingredients.append(newIngredient)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But when I do that, another problem appears. When I load that 
table view where that Custom cell is, it fails, and it says: index out of range.
What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: @Alen What line is failing specifically with that error?

Comment: @CodeLogic At this line: 
let  ingredient = ingredients[indexPath.row]
in my console output I get: fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: Then you dont have the `numberOfRowsInSection` code above or you are adding a row without adding an `ingredient` to the `ingredients` array

Comment: Thanks. Now when that ViewController loads I have no cells. My array is now empty so I have to implement some code to addButton which creates another cell and reloads tableView. How can I do that?

Comment: @Alen I updated the answer with some code for that. It looks like you're using core data, so you may need to do `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject` to create a new ingredient, but then append it to the ingredients array and reload the table.

Comment: My main problem isn't Core Data, I have a button that stores ingredient on button tap. That button stores whole cell (3 textfields for name, price and amount of ingredient and normative from dropdown button inside cell). But my main problem is, why my cells sometimes repeat itself and why I have problem calculating price when I add more than two cells.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, you have repeating cells because of the first issue I mentioned. Doing add with the updated `addButtonPressed` will generate new cells for you.

Comment: When I do that I get error on addButtonPressed on third line that says: missing argument for parameter 'name' in call
What that means ?

Comment: The only thing in the code i posted that could be wrong is the instantiation of the ingredient object, which would probably need to be change to a core data instantiation, thats why i mentioned in the comment you need to probably do an `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject`